# Is there a pythonic way to iterate over two lists one element at a time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists: [1, 2, 3] and [10, 20, 30]. Is there a way to iterate moving one element in each list in each step? Ex
(1, 10)
(1, 20)
(2, 20)
(2, 30)
(3, 30)
I know zip moves one element in both lists in each step, but that's not what I'm looking for

Comment: Yep. ```zip``` is the fastest way

Comment: Actually, `zip` doesn't produce that result. I don't see a regular pattern there.

Comment: It's not Zip if you look at OP's example.  I think you just need to write a custom while loop to do that?

Comment: Why is there no `(1, 30)` in your desired result?

Comment: they're alternating which index they increment (n,m),(n+1,m)(n+1,m+1),(n+2,m+1),(n+2,m+2)

Answer (score 4):

Is it what you expect:

```
def zip2(l1, l2):
    for i, a in enumerate(l1):
        for b in l2[i:i+2]:
            yield (a, b)
```

```
>>> list(zip2(l1, l2))
[(1, 10), (1, 20), (2, 20), (2, 30), (3, 30)]
```

Answer (score 1):

For good measure, here's a solution that works with arbitrary iterables, not just indexable sequences:

```
def frobnicate(a, b):
    ita, itb  = iter(a), iter(b)
    flip = False
    EMPTY = object()

    try:
       x, y = next(ita), next(itb)
       yield x, y
    except StopIteration:
        return

    while True:
        flip = not flip
        if flip:
            current = y = next(itb, EMPTY)
        else:
            current = x = next(ita, EMPTY)
        if current is EMPTY:
            return
        yield x, y
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def dupe(l): 
    return [val for val in l for _ in (0,1)]

list(zip(dupe([1,2,3]), dupe([10,20,30])[1:]))
# [(1, 10), (1, 20), (2, 20), (2, 30), (3, 30)]
```

One with zip and list comprehension.